# Role of % sign in printf statement in following cases

Tags: c, printf

I am unable to understand the outputs in the following two cases.
Compiler:Borland C++ 5.02 on windows
CASE 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "HELLO";
    printf("%abc %2s", str, str);
    return 0;
}
output:%abc %2s
```

CASE 2:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char str[] = "HELLO";
    printf("abc %2s", str, str);  //% sign removed
    return 0;
}
output:abc 1310540
```

Please make me understand the outputs.Pardon if it sounds childish.I am kind of naive in C.

Comment: And what is your exact question?

Comment: What are you expecting each of the two versions to do?

Comment: Can u plz make me understand the ouputs

Comment: Can't reproduce your output. `%a` expects a double argument, where you give it two strings, but even though the result is strictly speaking undefined, this should still not result in the output you quote, i.e. the unformatted string. And although the second `str` argument in the second case is unneccessary, there should be no number printed instead of the string. What compiler and what C library (or what operating system) are you using?

Comment: i am using borland C++ on windows

Comment: Why don't you pass arguments that match your format strings? Arguing about undefined behaviour is a little pointless. I suggest you fix your code first.

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Comment: Also Borland C++ has had many many different versions. What version are you using? Let me guess, 5.5?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan that's okay but m keen to know the peculiarity  of the outputs

Comment: You need to tag the question with the compiler and version.

Comment: I also do not believe that the CASE 2 program produces that output. Try pasting it from this question into an editor, compiler and run.

Comment: AFAIR the `%a` specifier came with C99. Perhaps the C library on windows still doesn't implement that bit? and then because there is no valid specifier (for them) it prints the `%` character as such? Just speculating.

Comment: @JensGustedt This is bcc v5.02, it must be 15 years old if it's a day. And there is no "C library on Windows". Each toolset has its own.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan http://codepad.org/oyemZi21#output
see the outputs here

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, even worse than I though. So discussing such a thing really makes no sense, voting to close.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes, one Q is UB, the other is fake code. Not good.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan sir The output in the question is from compiler in my pc.That's y it differs from the pastebin output.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Please don't close the question

Comment: @Aakash, I think you have received enough information in the comments and in the answers. You should definitively move to a more recent compiler.

Comment: @JensGustedt plz sugest me one

Comment: on windows use gcc port, mingw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my guess:

```
printf("%abc %2s", str, str);
```

Your ancient compiler pre-dates the introduction of the `%a` format string. So the runtime realises that it has encountered a format string that it does not recognise and gives up attempting to format. In any case, you cannot pass a string to `%a` and expect anything meaningful. So, even if your compiler understood '%a', the behaviour would be undefined. There's little to be gained from attempting to understand UB. Fix your code.

```
printf("abc %2s", str, str);
```

should output

```
abc HELLO
```

even on your ancient compiler. If it does not, that's a bug in the runtime for the compiler.

I personally am prepared to bet that your compiler will produce that output for that program. I rather imagine that your question has been transcribed incorrectly. Either the output in the question does not match the code, or vice versa.

And that's confirmed by your pastebin:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char str[] = "HELLO";
    printf("abc %d", str, str);//different from code in question

    return 0;
}

Output: abc -1083086374
```

So, not only is it a little pointless discussing UB, it's even more pointless discussing a program when the version you are running differs from the code in the question. In future I urge you to use copy/paste to transfer code into a Stack Overflow question, and double and triple check that the output is what you claim it to be.

Bottom line: It's 2013 now. There's no reason to be using BCC v5.02. It's time to step forward in time.

Comment: See the outputs here http://codepad.org/oyemZi21#output

Comment: Your example uses `%d` to display a string, which is expected to show something other than a string. Exactly what, as described above about `%a` when you pass a string as the value, is undefined. The compiler/runtime is allowed to do whatever the heck it wants, including launching nuclear missiles, wipe your hard disk or just print the string you passed in. Most likely it will do none of the three examples I gave, but rather print some "random" number. I don't mean random as in "completely impossible to figure out what it is" or "different every time", but rahter "I can't tell you..."

Comment: @Aakash I updated the answer. Your question contains an error.

Comment: The output in the question is from compiler in my pc.That's y it differs from the pastebin output

Comment: @MatsPetersson sir The output in the question is from compiler in my pc.That's y it differs from the pastebin output

Comment: Never mind that the source code differs from what you posted above, I guess? Yes, if you feed a string to "%d", you'll (most likely) get some numbers that nobody who hasn't spent FAR too much time with that particular development environment can figure out. If you use a modern compiler, such as GCC, you will also get a warning, which helps you NOT DO THAT!

Answer (score 0):

The first is undefined behaviour, since you try put a string to be printed as a hex floating point.

The second example is valid. It prints a string with a minimum of two characters.The second argument `str` is ignored.

Comment: So, how does "HELLO" become `1310540`?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It doesn't.

Comment: Are you going to elaborate on that comment? I cannot understand what you mean.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Compile the second example with a C compiler. it produces `abc HELLO` http://ideone.com/t9YKVb

Comment: @Armin: The OP is claiming that he sees `1310540` in place of `HELLO` in his second case.

Comment: It's plausible that bcc32 v5.02 is not what you or I would recognise as "a C compiler"! But you are probably right. Even that probably produces `abc HELLO`.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to say that you need to just read the [full POSIX documentation for `printf`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) (you can also type `man 3p printf` from a Linux console) or the documentation with your compiler / C Standard Library implementation.

Basically, characters encountered after a `%` character are interpreted in a very specific way.  The characters following a `%` fall into the categories of "flags", "length modifiers" and "conversion specifies" -- each of these are optional except for the conversion specifier.  Your 2nd example should have given you a warning because you had more values than you had conversion specifiers and it even appears to have a bug because you cannot use the numeric flag (the "2") with the string conversion specifier and it spit out nonsense (maybe your pointer in decimal).